# How to keep original line and ammended line with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I am learning C# and I would like some help. With the help of the people on I have managed to achieve editing an .inf file section using a regex, but I would like to keep the original line of text before editing. I have placed the code below and a sample of the .INF data before and if possible what I would like it to look like, but not too bothered with how it will look as long as the data is there.

```
else if (!chkbxintdial.Checked)
{
   var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtcurrent.Text).ToList();
   var regex = new Regex(@"^[00]{2}");
   var startFrom = lines.IndexOf("[Destinations]");

   //Start replacing from the index of "[Destinations]"
   for (int i = startFrom; i < lines.Count; i++)
   {
      //Assuming the ini section ends at an empty line - stop replacing
      if (lines[i].Trim() == string.Empty)
      break;

      lines[i] = regex.Replace(lines[i], "+");
   }
   File.WriteAllLines(txtnewtariff.Text, lines);
```

Sample of what I would like to do.

Original file

```
[Destinations]
00="International",I,IV
0024195="Gabon Mobiles",I,IMT
0024197="Gabon Mobiles",I,IMT
```

After Process.

```
[Destinations]
00="International",I,IV
+="International",I,IV
0024195="Gabon Mobiles",I,IMT
+24195="Gabon Mobiles",I,IMT
0024197="Gabon Mobiles",I,IMT
+24197="Gabon Mobiles",I,IMT
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than replacing the line entirely, add onto the line instead:

```
lines[i] += Environment.NewLine + regex.Replace(lines[i], "+");
```

It's also worth noting that there are tools that exist specifically for manipulating .INF files, so beyond doing so for academic purposes, there really isn't a need to do this.  While your solution (barring this little fix) seems like it will work, it's not particularly efficient for larger files, nor is it particularly robust in the face of arbitrary data.

Comment: Thank you for the help and advice. The application has a particular use that needs to be simple as I know that even a Macro would have been fine.

Comment: Question this is failing as it is writing 
[Destinations]
[Destinations]    so when the code loops it finds no new entrysany ideas?

Comment: @MatthewRingsell Your `for` loop should start at `startFrom+1`, not `startFrom`.